# scanf doesn't work because of dup2

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Scanf (actually i tried any number of scanf's) skips after duplicating socket descriptor. Here is code you can compile to see the problem:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main()
{
    int listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int dupfd = 0;
    dup2(listenfd, dupfd);

    puts("Type something to exit");
    int exit = -1;
    scanf("%d", &exit);
    puts("Got exit signal");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect this to work? The socket has not been connected to another socket (if this is client code). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is part of my server code for people who would like to help me. Of course exactly this code does nothing and pretty useless

Comment: @snoopy-whoopy, "Of course exactly this code does nothing and pretty useless."  Exactly so.  Present an MCVE if you actually want help.

Comment: @John Bollinger, But this is minimal example. You can compile it and see the problem. It's all because of dup2 but I don't know how to fix this

Comment: Another thing, the listening fd does not return data from a client. You should dup2() the socket returned by accept() for this to have any chance to work.

Comment: @epx, Actually I'm concerned about scanf at first. But thanks a lot

Comment: scanf() is also inadequate to parse network messages. I extended my answer below explaining why.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. As a result, it's impossible to figure out what help you need. Do you want an explanation of why this happens? It's not clear why you think this is a problem -- the code does exactly what you should expect and if you want something else, write code to do that something else. You don't tell us what you're trying to do, so what are we supposed to do?

Comment: @David Schwartz, I just want to duplicate this descriptor having working scanf

Comment: Then use `dup` instead of `dup2`.\

Comment: Also, avoid calling your variable `exit`, since there's a standard function with that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clearer if you use a mere `read` instead of a `scanf` and control errno:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main()
{
    int listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int dupfd = 0;
    dup2(listenfd, dupfd);

    puts("Type something to exit");
    int exit = -1;
    //scanf("%d", &exit);
    char buf[16];
    int n = read(0, buf, 16);
    printf("Got %d (%d)\n", n, errno);
    puts("Got exit signal");

    return 0;
}
```

The program output `Got -1 (57)`, because after the `dup2`, you are trying to read from a listen socket. So you get a read error with cause `ENOTCONN`: Socket is not connected

All this happens because of the `dup2`. Here are some extracts from the man page: *The dup() system call duplicates an existing object descriptor... In dup2(), the value of the new descriptor newd is specified.  If this descriptor is already in use and oldd != newd, the descriptor is first deallocated as if the close(2) system call had been used.*

And 0, 1 and 2 are *standard* file descriptor: 1=input, 2=output, 3=error. So `int dupfd = 0; dup2(listenfd, dupfd);` closes standard input and makes it a copy of `listenfd`. After that, all `scanf` or `read(0, ...)` act on `listendfd`. IMHO, what you wanted to do is simply:

```
int dupfd = dup(listenfd);
```

That way you actually get a copy of `listenfd`, but on an unused file descriptor instead of reusing standard input.

Comment: This just explains the problem. I do not try to fix, because you just cannot read from a listen socket, and I do not know if you want to read from an accepted socket, or anything else

Comment: Please, explain me, why am I reading from a socket but not from a stdin. I don't understand this. Thanks for problem resolving!

Comment: @snoopy-whoopy stdin has file descriptor number 0, your dup2() call replaces file descriptor 0 with your socket. Thus when you try to read from stdin, you're trying to read from the socket.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta, Thanks a lot again! I thought dup2 is only another representation of dup

Answer (score 2):

I guess the error is, you should dup2() the connection socket, not the listening socket. The following example worked for me (connect with telnet in port 32000 for testing):

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <strings.h>


int main()
{
    int listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int dupfd = 0;

   int connfd,n;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
   socklen_t clilen;

   bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000);
   bind(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

   listen(listenfd,1024);
   connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);
    dup2(connfd, dupfd);


    puts("Type something to exit");
    int exit = -1;
    scanf("%d", &exit);
    printf("%d\n", exit);
    puts("Got exit signal");

    return 0;
}
```

Have in mind that using scanf() on a socket is a bad idea, because scanf() only blocks once; that is, once it receives any part of the message, even a single character, it will parse the string it received. If it is not complete, the parse will be wrongful.

A network socket can deliver a message in any number of smaller chunks. Typically it will send it in packets, but it could even be character-by-character. This example "tends to work" with Telnet because the client side only sends the typed string when you press ENTER. But it is is completely inadequate for an actual network server.

Comment: But I need to duplicate exactly listenfd. If you don't mind to spend some time I could provide all my awful server code and explain why I need this. But thanks for this great decision, I will keep it in mind

Comment: @snoopy-whoopy, trying to read data from the listening socket (or a duplicate of it) is plain wrong.  You need to use the listening socket to accept a connection, and then dupe the resulting file descriptor for the connected socket.  *That's* the one from which you can read data.  I am now the third person to tell you this.